# Expectation of a symmetric function about zero

Tags: probability

I understand that the median of a symmetric function about zero is zero because 50% of the mass is contained either side of it. It is easy to prove this result for the Expectation,however I do not understand intuitively why the expectation of say the normal distribution is zero.

Comment: If $f$ is an even function, then $xf$ is an odd function, so that the integral over a symmetrical interval is zero

Comment: I unit understand the proof, it's the intuition i'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it help if you think of the mean as a balance point of the distribution? The statistical formula for the population mean based on a density function is (except for notation) the same as the physics formula for the center of gravity of a lamina (of shape defined by the density function).

If you look at an asymetrical distribution, then the mean and median 
are typically not the same.

In the plots below, the solid orange line shows the location of
the mean and the broken purple line shown the location of the median.
Same for normal, but not for exponential. The $areas$ on either side of the median are the same. In the exponential curve, the long tail to the right pulls the mean to the right of the median; the effect
is fairly strong because the tail extends to infinity.

[image]

Comment: I would have thought the median was the balance point of the distribution, seeing as 50% of the mass is either side of it?

Comment: No, if there is a long 'lever arm' in one direction that influences mean, but not necessarily median. Will post PDF of normal and exponential, that may help.

Comment: Maybe easier to consider samples. A: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5; has median 3 and mean 3. B: 1, 2, 3, 9, 40; has median 3 and mean 11.